# In clash of clans, how are attackable resources distributed between buildings?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans, how are attackable resources distributed between buildings?

For example, are more attackable resources put into higher level buildings?  Do resource storage buildings have more attackable resources?  If I have a level 1 mine and a level 6 mine, would it store resources in the level 6 mine before the level 1 mine?  Or would it split it between them (effectively maxing out the level 1 mine storage)?

The idea being if I had an extra level 1 mine outside of a defendable wall to make targeting more valuable resources inside the wall harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All resources are mined and stored individually:

- Level 1 gold mine can hold 500 gold max.
- Level 5 gold mine can hold 10,000 gold max.

If your storage is 100% full, attackers will gain more from your level 5 mine, than your level 1 mine.

Interestingly though, depending on your Town Hall level, the amount of total lootable resources actually declines as you level up:

- Level 1-5: 20% of total resources available to be looted.*
- Level 6: 18% of total resources available to be looted.*
- Level 7: 16% of total resources available to be looted.*
- Level 8: 14% of total resources available to be looted.*
- Level 9: 12% of total resources available to be looted.*
- Level 10: 10% of total resources available to be looted.*

*Gold and Elixir only. Differs for Dark Elixir.

Comment: Those percentages are for storages

Comment: Yes, sorry if I did not make that clear :)

Answer (score 2):

Mines mine and store independently. Your level 1 mine will mine slower and store less simply because it is a lower level.